# Instance_eval does not work with do/end block, only with {}-blocks

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

If I have a class:

```
class KlassWithSecret
  def initialize
    @secret = 99
  end
end
```

and run:

```
puts KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval { @secret }
```

it prints 99, but if I run:

```
puts KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval do
  @secret
end
```

It returns an error: `` `instance_eval': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3) (ArgumentError) ``

Why can't I use do/end blocks with `instance_eval`?

P.S. I am using Ruby 2.1.0.

Comment: works here (ruby 2.0.0) what ruby version are you using?

Comment: Works for me (2.1.0). Are you sure the code you pasted causes an error?

Comment: Cann't reproduce in 1.9.3 . If you have some older/different Ruby implementation it may something to do with lower precedence of `do..end` block then `{..}` block.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to use it with `puts`, my bad. Edited the question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/), …

Comment: … [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/), [Why aren't `do`/`end` and `{}` always equivalent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7487664/), [Wierd imperfection in Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7620804/), [Passing block into a method - Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/10909496/), [`instance_eval` block not supplied?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/12175788/), and [block syntax difference causes “`LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`”](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/18623447/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you pass block with curly braces, it is passed to `instance_eval` method. But if you pass it with `do-end`, it's passed to `puts` method, so `instance_eval` doesn't get block and raises an error.

Answer (score 5):

Enclose expression supplied to `puts` in parenthesis because lower precedence of `do..end` block.

```
puts( KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval do
  @secret
end )
```

or use brace syntax of block

```
puts KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval {
  @secret
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you use do..end block, the block is passed to the puts function. The code with do..end block will work if you write it like this

```
puts(KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval do
  @secret
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Proc.new {@secret}
puts KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval(&a)
# 99
```

It say that `puts KlaccWithSecret do @secret end` does not gain the `Proc`(block).

Answer (score -1):

Ruby(2.0.0) works.
Code:

```
KlassWithSecret.new.instance_eval do
  p @secret
end
# 99
```

no problem.

Comment: It works because you're missing the call to `puts`.

Comment: I think deeply. I post a new answer. Hope that can help you.

Comment: @toro2k I think It is a code golf... :)